# Button redirect error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to a redirect the user when they click on a specific button

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Server.Transfer("ControlPanel/Default.aspx");
}
```

The problem is when I click Button1 it redirects me to another page

```
localhost:57988/WebSite5/Default.aspx
```

and the weirdest thing is it open another page with this link above, not the default page I have, but another but with the default.aspx page url that you see!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not doing a redirect, you are doing a transfer. That means that the execution continues with the new page, but the URL doesn't change. The page that you transferred to is returned as response to the request for the first page.

Use `Response.Redirect` instead of `Server.Transfer` to do a redirect.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `Server.Transfer` it won't display the new URL in the query string.  Could it be that is what's throwing you off?

[Here is a good article](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3299641/ServerTransfer-Vs-ResponseRedirect.htm) on `Response.Redirect` vs `Server.Transfer`.  If you really want to redirect the user then you should use `Response.Redirect`.